# ActionView::MissingTemplate in Users#comments

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

I'm getting a missing partial error in my Rails app, even though I created the partial file! I'm a little stumped. Here is the error I'm seeing:

```
ActionView::MissingTemplate in Users#comments
Missing partial comments/comment with {:locale=>[:en], :formats=>[:html], :handlers=>[:erb, :builder, :coffee]}. Searched in:
  * "/home/bruce/rails_projects/appname/app/views"
  * "/home/bruce/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p0/gems/devise-2.2.4/app/views"

app/views/users/show_comment.html.erb:24:in `_app_views_users_show_comment_html_erb___2848231870651058222_30950520'
app/controllers/users_controller.rb:59:in `comments'
```

Here's the view that calls the partial:

```
                <% if @user.comments.any? %>
                 <h3><%= render @comments %></h3>
                 </ol>
```

Here's the relevant code for the Users controller:

```
def comments
    @user = User.find(params[:id])
    @comments = @user.comments.all
    render 'show_comment'
  end
```

I named the partial show_comment.html.erb, which is the correct file name. I'm actually doing something similar with a different page called show_post and it works fine. I'm comparing the code between the two and they seem identical. What's different here? What did I do wrong? I really need another set of eyes to review this for me.

Thanks!!
-b

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error is telling you that Rails is looking for a partial named `_comment.html.erb` in the comments folder because that would be the default partial name/location for an array of comments.  Add a file and  your partial code there.  Something like:

```
<li><%= comment.value %></li>
```

You won't need the h3 tags around the partial call in your show comments view.

Comment: You were right. I was missing _comment.html.erb in the comments folder. Thanks again!